# RegexExp not capturing group properly

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to eliminate some characters if found in my string like v_[i] will be v.To do this I am using RegExp but it is not capturing the group.

```
var string='v_[i]';
var regexExp = new RegExp('_[\w+]','ig');
var finalstring = string.replace(regexExp,'');
alert(finalstring);
```

While in the other hand if i use a literal string it works perfectly

```
var finalstring = string.replace(/_\[\w+\]/ig,'');
```

then why RegExp not capturing the group as the literal string does.

Comment: `new RegExp('_[\w+]','ig')` You forgot to escape your brackets and backslashes --> should be `new RegExp('_\\[\\w+\\]','ig')`

Comment: it worked fine,why need to add extra slashes?

Comment: That is because when you are creating a regexp with the constructor you are passing in a string. Any `\ ` in the string will first escape the next character before passing it to the constructor, and therefore `'_[\w+]'` becomes `_[w+]`.

Comment: I got it but why we are using the double slash as for escape a single slash should work?

Comment: Because a single backslash *doesn't* work.

Comment: Thanks a lot add your answer,I will mark it correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126578/discussion-between-syed-kamran-ahmed-and-derek-).

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the brackets in your regex:

```
var string = 'v_[i]';
var regexExp = /_\[\w+\]/ig;
var finalstring = string.replace(regexExp, '');
```

Comment: You're right. It is somehow redundant. I'll correct my answer.